# Truncating text with Pipes in Angular 4 and PrimeNg

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to display the output of a data-table with the limit of 150 characters.
I have a pipe that is defined as:

```
transform(value: string, args: string[]): string {
    const limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 20;
    const trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';
    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
   }
```

My HTML is:

```
p-column field="description" header="Description">
            <ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body" >
                <span #z>{{ z | truncate:[20] }}</span>
            </ng-template>
        </p-column>
```

This is the output I see on my webpage:

```
[object HTMLSpanElement]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `#z` from your `span`. Currently in your template `z` is considered as span element and same has been passed to `truncate` Pipe.

```
<span>{{ z | truncate:[20] }}</span>
```